# hibernate query sql ,five records but return two

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my case , hibernate sent sql

```sql
select resources0_.role_id     as role_id5_17_0_,
       resources0_.id          as id1_17_0_,
       resources0_.id          as id1_17_1_,
       resources0_.create_time as create_t2_17_1_,
       resources0_.update_time as update_t3_17_1_,
       resources0_.resource_id as resource4_17_1_,
       resources0_.role_id     as role_id5_17_1_,
       resource1_.id           as id1_14_2_,
       resource1_.create_time  as create_t2_14_2_,
       resource1_.update_time  as update_t3_14_2_,
       resource1_.icon         as icon4_14_2_,
       resource1_.link         as link5_14_2_,
       resource1_.name         as name6_14_2_,
       resource1_.parent_id    as parent_i9_14_2_,
       resource1_.sort         as sort7_14_2_,
       resource1_.type         as type8_14_2_,
       resource2_.id           as id1_14_3_,
       resource2_.create_time  as create_t2_14_3_,
       resource2_.update_time  as update_t3_14_3_,
       resource2_.icon         as icon4_14_3_,
       resource2_.link         as link5_14_3_,
       resource2_.name         as name6_14_3_,
       resource2_.parent_id    as parent_i9_14_3_,
       resource2_.sort         as sort7_14_3_,
       resource2_.type         as type8_14_3_
from role_resource resources0_
         left outer join resource resource1_ on resources0_.resource_id = resource1_.id
         left outer join resource resource2_ on resource1_.parent_id = resource2_.id
where resources0_.role_id = 24
```

I hava run it and I get five records
[image]

when  I want to get results, only two can be found. I do not know what is going wrong
[image]

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package com.gtft.labour.security.rbac.domain;

import com.gtft.labour.entity.BaseEntity;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
//@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class RoleResource  extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    private Resource resource;
}
```

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package com.gtft.labour.security.rbac.domain;

import com.gtft.labour.entity.BaseEntity;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@ToString(callSuper = true)
//@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Role extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<RoleResource> resources  = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RoleUserTableEntity> admins = new HashSet<>();

    private Integer level;
}
```

This is my resource.java

```java
package com.gtft.labour.security.rbac.domain;

import com.gtft.labour.entity.BaseEntity;
import com.gtft.labour.security.rbac.dto.ResourceInfo;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
//@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@ToString(callSuper = true)
//@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Resource extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String link;

    private String icon;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ResourceType type;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> urls;

    @ManyToOne
    private Resource parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @OrderBy("sort ASC")
    private List<Resource> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    public ResourceInfo toTree(UserTableEntity admin) {
        ResourceInfo result = new ResourceInfo();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, result);
        Set<Long> resourceIds = admin.getAllResourceIds();

        List<ResourceInfo> children = new ArrayList<ResourceInfo>();
        for (Resource child : getChilds()) {
            if(resourceIds.contains(child.getId())){
                children.add(child.toTree(admin));
            }
        }
        result.setChildren(children);
        return result;
    }


    public void addChild(Resource child) {
        childs.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    private int sort;

}
```

And service code :

```java
public void setRoleResources(Long roleId, String resourceIds) {
        resourceIds = StringUtils.removeEnd(resourceIds, ",");
        Role role = roleRepository.findById(roleId).get();
        Set<RoleResource> resources = role.getResources();//this line I found the problem,wrong results
        roleResourceRepository.deleteAll(resources);
        String[] resourceIdArray = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(resourceIds, ",");
        for (String resourceId : resourceIdArray) {
            RoleResource roleResource = new RoleResource();
            roleResource.setRole(role);
            Optional<Resource> resource =
                    resourceRepository.findById(new Long(resourceId));
            resource.ifPresent(value -> {
                log.warn("resource:{}", value);
                roleResource.setResource(value);
            });
            roleResourceRepository.save(roleResource);
        }
    }
```

As far as I think , maybe problem is I used wrong **onetomany** and **manytoone** in role class and role_resource class,
it beyond my ability.

Comment: It is quite normal for JPA to combine multiple rows from a `ResultSet` in a single entity. So from what you have shown so far I don't see a reason to assume something is wrong.

Comment: I updated my post, I have no idea where is wrong

Comment: Could it be a problem with the Collection type, Set? Set doesn't allow duplicate entries and java determines that through the equals method of the Object. I see you commented out the equals annotation in your code, so if your super class has an equals, only that one will be used. could you try implement it or switch to List instead of Set?

Comment: @PaulD you saved my day, I know exactly where is wrong

Comment: reposted my comment as answer so it can be marked as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Solution found in comments. Reposting as answer so it can be marked as solution.*

It is most likely a problem with the Collection type, `Set`. Set doesn't allow duplicate entries and java determines that through the `equals` method of the object.

I see you commented out the equals annotation in your code, so if your super class `BaseEntity` has an `equals` method, only that one will be used. You have to either swap `Set` to `List` or update / implement `equals` correctly in your classes.